# How can I loop through a large UL list faster?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a dropdown in a project that I'm building in Google Sheets that has a search function but it takes 15 seconds or more to update the list. How can I make a search function for a large list (in this instance, 16k items) that updates quickly?

Here's what I've got.

The HTML

```
<div id="cityList">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="citySearch" oninput="filterCities">
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li> {list of items generated from function} </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The Javascript

```
function filterCities() {
    var cities = document.querySelectorAll('#cityList ul li')
    var query = document.querySelector('#citySearch').value

    for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
        if (cities[i].innerText.includes(query) == false) {
            cities[i].classList.add('hide')
        } else {
            cities[i].classList.remove('hide')
        }
    }
}
```

The CSS

```
.hide {
     display: none;
}
```

The unordered list is generated from a function when the HTML loads. For this project, users will need to set a location and the list of cities comes from the API that requires the setting.

### What I've Tried

Through some testing, I've learned that both the includes() and the classList.add are the primary issue here. When I test my functions in the browser console on an object, rather than an HTML list item it's acceptably quick (not fast, but not user-experience breaking). Some things I've tried to remedy this are:

- Changing classList.add to classList.toggle. This didn't notably improve the speed.
- Changing classList.add to className += ' hide'. This also didn't notably improve the speed

What I plan to try next is to filter the list as an object and essentially 'replace' the list oninput. I suspect this might be faster but still take a few seconds to write the li elements to the page.

Is there a way to search through a *large* list of items and filter them that is acceptably responsive on the front end?

Comment: The loop itself is probably almost instant. The DOM access is probably the slow part. Avoid using the DOM as the source of your data, keep an array separate from the DOM, and use that as the source of truth for your data. Also, you don't need touch every single element by adding the `hide` class, you only need to show the relevelant elements. Rebuilding an entirely new `ul` list with only the matched elements will probably be faster

Comment: Also if your array is millions of entries long, or larger, you probably want to move your search to the server. Also on the server or client, some kind of index could help the search itself

Comment: Do you really need all list items to be loaded in the DOM?? Do you expect users to find it useful to scroll over 16K entries? I know I wouldn't. So, don't do that. You can keep it in memory, and search in memory. If you want, show the 20 best matches in the DOM, but not 16K.

Comment: @AndyRay That's what I was finding and my next step was going to be storing an object in the window and replacing the results with each input. I was unfamiliar with debouncing (though it functionally makes sense) so your snippet below is an excellent solution.

Comment: @trincot no, probably not and it's a point well taken. THe UX of the element probably needs some consideration. I'm treating it as a drop-down but with AndyRay's solution, it might be better as an input field and then I'm not creating a scrollable list of 16k results at any point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your source of truth of data out of the DOM, and into vanilla Javascript data (objects and arrays). Don't touch every DOM element on every search, instead, build an entirely new list every time with the matched elements.

You should probably also debounce your search, and limit the number of matches.

Regardless, this is pretty much instant on 16k entries. See these strategies [applied in this CodePen](https://codepen.io/andrewray/pen/ZEVEwmN).

Abbreviated code, but there's nothing special here, it's basically just filtering an array:

```js
const MIN_SEARCH_LENGTH = 0;
const DEBOUNCE_MS = 200;

const resultContainer = document.getElementById('result');
const resultCountContainer = document.getElementById('resultCount');

const debounce = (func, delay) => {
  let debounceTimer;
  return function() {
    const context = this;
    const args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(debounceTimer);
    debounceTimer = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), delay);
  }
}

const search = (searchText) => {
  const lowered = searchText.toLowerCase();
  const found = new Set();
  if(searchText.length > MIN_SEARCH_LENGTH) {
    const matched = window.lowerCased.reduce((indices, lower, index) => {
      if(lower.includes(lowered)) {
        found.add(window.cities[index]);
      }
      return indices;
    }, found);
  }
  return [...found];
}

const applyFilter = (searchText) => {
  const foundCities = search(searchText);
  const total = foundCities.length;
  resultContainer.innerHTML = foundCities.map(c => `<li>${c}</li>`).join('');
  resultCountContainer.innerText = `Found ${total} result${total > 1 ? 's' : ''}`;
}
const onChange = (e) => applyFilter(e.target.value);
const debounced = debounce(onChange, DEBOUNCE_MS);

const input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
input.addEventListener('keyup', debounced);

window.cities = ["New York"...];
window.lowerCased = window.cities.map(c => c.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: Admittedly, I'm a bit of a JS novice so some of what you've built in here I would not have been able to repeat myself.

I did manage to get it to work in my project though and it works beautifully so thank you!! And I'll study the elements I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

It should work way smoother with this function instead :

```
function filterCities() {
    const cities = document.querySelectorAll('#cityList ul li');
    const query = document.querySelector('#citySearch').value.toLowerCase();

    for (const city of cities) {
        const cityName = city.textContent.toLowerCase();
        city.classList.toggle('hide', !cityName.includes(query));
    }
}
```

- Use `.textContent` instead of `.innerText` since it's generally faster.
- Use `for...of` loop instead of the traditional `for` loop which can be slightly slower.
- Use `.toggle()` instead of directly manipulating the class to reduce the reflow.
- Use Case-Insensitive search by converting both the query and the city to lowercase (Optional).
- You should go with `const` (or `let` if not constant) instead of `var` inside your function (Best Practice).
- It would be better if you can store the DOM elements outside the function to avoid querying them each time the function is called (if possible).

**Side Note :** just like 'Andy Ray' mentioned, displaying 16k elements to the user is not quite practical, instead you can go for `Pagination` or `Infinite Scroll` for better user experience.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm going with the route that Andy Ray suggested but your notes here on which methods are faster than others is super useful!

Comment: If you're going to use the DOM as your source of truth (bad), don't read from the DOM in a loop, because DOM access is very slow, including reads. Cache the cities from the DOM into a vanilla array instead, outside of the function, to minimize DOM access.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const SIZE = 16_000;
const MS_DEBOUNCE = 200;

async function fetchUsers() {
  const maxApiUsersSize = 100;
  const apiUsersSize = Math.min(SIZE, maxApiUsersSize);
  const apiUsers = await fetch(`https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/users?size=${apiUsersSize}`).then(r => r.json());
  
  if (apiUsersSize == SIZE) {
    return apiUsers;
  }
  const users = new Array(SIZE);

  for (let i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
    users[i] = apiUsers[i % maxApiUsersSize];
  }
  
  return users
}

function createLi(user) {
  const li = document.createElement('li')

  li.innerText = user.first_name;
  
  return li;
}

function shouldKeepUser(user, searchValue) {
  if (!searchValue) {
    return true;
  }

  return user.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue);
}

fetchUsers().then(users => {
  let filteredUsers = users;

  list.append(...filteredUsers.map(createLi));

  let searchTimeoutId = null;

  search.oninput = (e) => {
    clearTimeout(searchTimeoutId);
    searchTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      const { value } = e.target;

      if (!value) {
        filteredUsers = users;
      } else {
        filteredUsers = users.filter(user => shouldKeepUser(user, value));
      }

      list.innerHTML = "";
      list.append(...filteredUsers.map(createLi));
    }, MS_DEBOUNCE);
  }

});
```

```html
<label for="search">
  Search
</label>

<input id="search" name="search" type="text" />

<ol id="list">
</ol>
```